# react-dropdown-select arrow key is not highlighting item

Tags: reactjs

Hello stackoverflow so I am using a package called react-dropdown-select. However when I am moving my arrow key down, the items in my list are not focused. Here is my code

```
<Select
          className={this.props.className}
          color="dodgerblue"
          separator={true}
          searchable={true}
          keepOpen={false}
          dropdownHandle={true}
          multi={false}
          labelField={"label"}
          valueField={"value" ? "value" : "null"}
          options={this.props.options}
          dropdownGap={0}
          selectable={true}
          keepSelectedInList={true}
          dropdownPosition={"bottom"}
          onChange={this.onChangeHandler}
          noDataLabel={
            inlineTranslate
              ? this.props.intl.formatMessage({ id: "noOptionsAvailable" })
              : "No options available"
          }
          disabled={this.props.disabled}
          values={this.props.values}
          contentRenderer={this.contentRenderer}
        />
```

This is happening when I am pressing the down arrow key and the items are not being
focused/highlighted.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what fixed it for me was removing the color attritbute.

```
color="dodgerblue"
```